# Restarting managed servers by clusters without outage

Tags: weblogic, restart, weblogic11g

I want to write script for restarting weblogics managed servers, which would do the following:

It would contain loop ,which would restart first nodes of all clusters at one time.

```
  a.)FORCE_SHUTDOWN
  b.)wait for status: SHUTDOWN
  c.)START managed servers
  d.)wait for status: RUNNING
  e.)move to next node of each cluster and repeat until all managed servers are restarted.
```

So in first iteration it would restart all first nodes of each cluster, in second iteration it would restart the second nodes of each cluster and repeat this action until all managed servers are restarted.

I have not started to writing the script yet, I am newbie with weblogic and this is just concept. Do you have any suggestions how to achieve that goal?

Answer (score 1):

Why reinvent [the wheel](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/wls/WLSTC/reference.htm#WLSTC3784)?

> **rollingRestart**
>   Category: Control Commands
>
> Use with WLST: Online
>
> *Description*   Initiates a rolling restart of all servers in a domain or all servers in a specific cluster or clusters without interrupting
>   the service. This command provides the ability to sequentially restart
>   servers.
>
> This operation involves the graceful shutdown of the servers, and the
>   servers being restarted without interrupting the service for the user.
>
> *Syntax*
>
> ```
> rollingRestart(target, [options])
> ```